# Poskining like someone on their Yahrtzeit

Tags: posek-psak-decisor-ruling, yahrtzeit

I have heard in the name of Rav Yisroel Salanter that there is an inyan to poskin like a given posek on their Yahrtzeit, even if we would not poskin like them the rest of the year.

Two questions: 
1) Where is this recorded?
2) Do we have any record of it being used in a psak? For example, if someone would want to do some sort of elective surgery that is subject to a machlokes achronim, they could be suggested to schedule it for the yahrtzeit of the Acharon that matirs it.

Note: I understand that even those who hold during Sefiras HaOmer you say "LaOmer" will still refer to the 33rd day as "Lag BaOmer" in respect of the Rema who held you say "BaOmer", and whos yahrtzeit falls on the 33rd day (in our fixed calendar). However, I believe that when actually counting the Omer that night those who say "LaOmer" do not switch to "BaOmer".

Comment: Wouldn't that cause many contradictions ?

Comment: Aren't there some Chasidim who skip kabbalistic preludes to Sefira on the Noda Bihuda's Yahrtzeit?

Comment: Maybe the reason people call it Lag BaOmer has nothing to do with this, but just is a remnant of a time before Chasidim when Eastern Ashkenazim said BaOmer and as a name it stuck. Like how many Jews who don't speak any Yiddish still say "Paysach".

Comment: Welcoem to Mi Yodeya, Silver. Can you better explain your question? I don't understand it at all. What does it mean to paskin like "someone". Like whom? And who's yahrtzeit are you referring to?